# How to format text file from command line and print (font size and page size) using a2ps

Tags: command-line, printing

I have a thermal printer (80mm Logic Controls LR2000E), connected via USB, to my Debian 11 machine. I want to use the printer to print a purchase order/quote, which I have in a text file. I need to be able to do this from the command line, as it is part of a script.

I installed the ppd file from the manufacturer's website (https://logiccontrols.com/product-drivers/).

This ppd only allows to specify one paper size by default. I changed it by hand to 80x300mm.

I can format (wordwrap etc) through awk and print the text file using

```
lp table.txt
```

This respects the ppd's described paper size, and prints the list:
[image: printout from lp]

But I would like to control the output more, use smaller font, add borders, etc., so I tried to use a2ps.
In the a2ps.cfg file I added the page size that I need:

```
# 80mm for BEMATECH LR2000E (in postscript points)
#      NAME     W      H     LLX   LLY   URX    URY
Medium: T80    280    850    25    55    219    560
```

But I don't know how to print my text through a2ps! I've been banging the keybourd for hours over several days, but don't know where to look for more information. It always prints the lower left-hand corner of the generated page instead of the whole thing:
[image]

a2ps generates what looks like the right output if I save it using the -o table.ps option, but it doesn't fit the page. If I open the ps file in atril (PDF viewer) I can confirm that the text is in the file, wordwrapped and all, and the page size is partly correct (80x353mm), but I can't print it any way.

The a2ps info page has a great deal about prettyprint, but not very much about paper sizes.

So:

1. Should I use another method? or if a2ps is the way to go:
2. Why does the output ps file grow 53mm? and
3. Why can't I print the whole ps file in stead of just the tail of it?

Comment: I'm only familiar with the Epson thermal printers, which are line printers and use the ESC/POS protocol. I'd suggest looking into the protocol that thing uses and see if there's something similar for your printer. As for the problem with printing only the tail end, I suspect it's a buffering issue, i.e. the Printer can't process enough and dumps most of the data only to print the tail end right before the EOF.

Comment: @polemon Thanks. I'm completely new to printer drivers--always used to just using the included cd for inkjets on windows machines. This is definitely an ESC/POS printer. That being the case, should I just learn ESC/POS then, and forget about postscript?

Comment: I can't say you must, but that's how I did it. I simply wrote my own set of programs to talk to the printer, and formated whatever I needed to print myself, etc. This is certainly the hard route, but it gives you full control. Especially when dealing with things like the paper cutter, etc.

Comment: When printing pictures, I did my own image transformation and had to print the image in chunks, because the internal memory of the printer was way too small. I think this is happening in your case too. Try printing it in smaller batches, so to say, without advancing or cutting the paper until the last chunk is printed (that's what I did in my case, too).

Comment: Is this the manual for your printer https://logiccontrols.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/LR2000-User-Manual-v1-2.pdf ? If it is, it is definitely an ESC/POS printer, and you should be able to send ESC/POS commands to it.

Comment: Look for a file `a2ps.info` and run the `info` command on it to get more documentation (just try `info a2ps` to start with).